# JSF 1.2 : Not able to retrieve bean values in xhtml page

Tags: jsf-1.2

Am using JSF 1.2 . I have a servlet. When this servlet is hit, am getting the data from request parameters, in doPost, and I need to set it in bean so that I can show it on xhtml page.

My code is like below.

```
userId= request.getParameter("userID");
MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
myBean.initialize(userId);
```

In initialize method of myBean am setting userId value into a globalVariable.

In my logs in bean, globalVariable value is getting printed. But its not getting displayed on xhtml page.

Am redirecting to xhtml page in doPost method like below,

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/html/index.jsf");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In index.xhtml page, I have

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.globalVariable}"></h:outputText>
```

In my phaselistener am not doing any thing much. I just have beforPhase method.

Why am I not able to print the value in jsf page but able to print the value in log in bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before forwarding, you need to put the bean in the scope, exactly there where JSF expects it.

If it's a request scoped bean, use `HttpServletRequest#setAttribute()`.

```
request.setAttribute("myBean", myBean);
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks BalusC. If myBean is session scoped ?

Comment: Set it as a session attribute then by `request.getSession().setAttribute("myBean", myBean)`.